# Row sum using mutate and select

Tags: r, dplyr

library(dplyr)

I have the following data:

```
d1 <- data_frame(
name = c("jim", "john", "jim", "john"),
`2012` = c(57, 58, 47, 57),
`2013` = c(14, 3, 3, 90))
```

I would like to create two new rows using mutate function so that I have the  totals for john and jim for each year. I would like the data to look like this:

```
d1 <- data_frame(
name = c("jim", "john", "jim", "john", "jim total", "john total"),
`2012` = c(57, 58, 47, 57, 104, 115 ),
`2013` = c(14, 3, 3, 90, 17, 93))
```

I've tried the following amoungst other things:

```
d1 %>% 
 mutate(jim total = rowSums(select(., contains("jim"))))
```

But I'm not quite getting what I want. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can summarise first and then bind them to your original df, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(d1,
           d1 %>% 
             group_by(name) %>% 
             summarise_all(funs(sum)) %>%
             mutate(name = paste0(name, '_total')))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 3
>    name       `2012` `2013`
>   <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>
> 1 jim            57     14
> 2 john           58      3
> 3 jim            47      3
> 4 john           57     90
> 5 jim_total     104     17
> 6 john_total    115     93
> ```

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense. Is there a way of naming the new row (5,6) within the same expression?

Comment: Updated with the '_total'

Comment: maybe you can do that in `group` step itself, `group_by(name = paste(name, "total"))`